# Switch button to controll a button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would realize a page to information privacy.

I have done this:

```
class Informativa extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            switchValue: false,
            permission: ""
        }
    }

    toggleSwitch = value => {
        this.setState({ switchValue: value });
      };

  render() {
    return(
// text about privacy

<Switch
                style={{ marginTop: 30, marginRight: 20}}
                onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
                value={this.state.switchValue}
            />
            {(!this.state.switchValue)
            ?
            <TouchableOpacity  
                style={ [style.button, style.buttonOK]}>
                <Text style={[style.buttonTesto]}>Accept</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            :
            <TouchableOpacity  disabled={true}
                style={ [style.button, style.buttonOK]}>
                <Text style={[style.buttonTesto]}>Accept</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>}
        </View>
```

What I would realize is something like a switch that when it is in "On" enable button, when it is in "off" disable the button.

At the moment don't change nothing.

How can I do?

Comment: What about instead of rendering two different `TouchableOpacity` based on `state.switchValue` why not use `TouchableOpacity` property `disabled` like this: `disabled={!this.state.switchValue}` ?

Comment: Mmmh maybe your idea is better! I have tried but it doesn't change, the TouchableOpacity button is always the same

Comment: @Jack23 if you do so, the TouchableOpacity will not look different. Also apply a different style if it's disabled!

Comment: @TobiasLins So I should create two different styles if it is able or disable?

Comment: @TobiasLins You are right :) So the question is how can I choose different style if it is disabled?

Comment: @Jack23
For example ```<TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: !this.state.disabled: 'white': 'grey' }} />``` or better try to use styled-components -> you can easily change the style if a prop is there!

Comment: @TobiasLins If I wrote in this way it gives me an error

Comment: @Jack23
Sorry there was a typo:
```backgroundColor: !this.state.disabled ? 'white' : 'grey'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I've written ReactNative. If it is the case that Switch accepts a disabled attribute, like many html inputs, this should do the trick so long as switchValue is a boolean.

```
// Switch disabled when switchValue == false (off)

<Switch style={{ marginTop: 30, marginRight: 20}}
        onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
        value={this.state.switchValue}
        disabled={this.state.switchValue}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Switch
       style={{ marginTop: 30, marginRight: 20}}
       onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
       value={this.state.switchValue}
       {this.state.switchValue ? disabled :  ""}
        />
```

Does something like that work?

Comment: It 's give me an error here: {this.state.switchValue ? disabled :  ""}